# Как повесить одно событие на кнопку для 2-х функции

Tags: jquery

```
let clone = $('.main-body__none').clone();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        let inputV = $('input').val();
        let textareaV = $('textarea').val();
        if(!inputV) {
            alert('Введите название в поле');
            return false;
        }
        if (!textareaV) {
            alert('Введите описание в поле');
            return false;
        }
        if ($('.main-body__none').length) {
            $('.main-body__none').remove();
        }
        let s = '';
        s += '<div class="main-body__task">';
        s += '<div class="input__value">';
        s += inputV;
        s += '</div>';
        s += '<div class="btn__close" onclick="javascript:removeItem(this)"><img src="img/close.png" alt="" /></div>';
        s += '<div class="btn__spoiler" onclick="javascript:slideUpElement(this);javascript:slideDownElement(this)"><img src="img/spoiler.png" alt="" /></div>';
        s += '<div class="textarea__value">';
        s += textareaV;
        s += '</div>';
        s += '</div>';
        $('.main-body__column_l').append(s);
        $('input').val('');
        $('textarea').val('');
    });
});
function removeItem(element) {
    $(element).closest('.main-body__task').remove();
    if(!$('.main-body__task').length) {
        $('.main-body__column_l').append(clone);
    }
}
function slideUpElement (element) 
{
    $(element).css({
        transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
        transition: '0.5s all'
    });
    $(element).next('.textarea__value').slideUp(500,slideDownElement);
}
function slideDownElement (element)
{
    $(element).next('.textarea__value').slideDown(500); 
}
```

Как повесить на вот эту кнопку 2 функции на одно и тоже событие и сделать так,при нажатии,элемент
на странице сворачивался,при еще одном нажатии разворачивался

Comment: <div class="btn__spoiler" onclick="javascript:slideUpElement(this);javascript:slideDownElement(this)"><img src="img/spoiler.png" alt="" /></div>'; на вот эту кнопку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function slideUpOrDown(element) {
  if ($(element).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(element).removeClass('opened');
    $(element).next('.textarea__value').slideDown(500); 
  } else {
    $(element).addClass('opened');
    $(element).css({
        transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
        transition: '0.5s all'
    });
    $(element).next('.textarea__value').slideUp(500, function() {
      slideUpOrDown(element);
    });
  }
}

<div class="btn__spoiler" onclick="slideUpOrDown(this)">...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,помогло,только немного переделал,ибо ваш вариант воспроизводил оба действия сразу за 1 клик

Comment: function slideUpOrDown(element) {
  if ($(element).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(element).removeClass('opened');
    $(element).next('.textarea__value').slideDown(500); 
    $(element).css({
        transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
        transition: '0.5s all'
    });
  } else {
    $(element).addClass('opened');
    $(element).css({
        transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
        transition: '0.5s all'
    });
    $(element).next('.textarea__value').slideUp(500);
  }
}

Comment: @Ostin Отлично. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.